# Is saying "the rate of change is five-thirds meters per second" equivalent to saying "the rate of change is five meters every three seconds"?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, intuition

I am a teaching assistant for a winter school course in basic algebra and I was explaining the meaning of the slope of a line to a student today using the following example: $$y = \frac{5}{3}x$$ where $y$ is measured in units of meters and $x$ is measured in units of time. I told them that the slope of the line is the rate of change of $y$ with respect to $x$, however, I then followed up by saying for this line in particular the rate of change is "five-thirds meters per second". This got me thinking, is this the same thing as saying "the rate of change is five meters every three seconds"? I concluded that these two statements do in fact mean the same thing since $\frac{5}{3} \cdot 3 = 5$ which precisely what you should have if you think about "your position" after $3$ seconds has elapsed.

I understand this is a little informal, but the concept to new students is important to me. Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: Yes, you can say that.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Of course, we want to be able to apply this when taken over an interval of time that is not an exact multiple of $3$ seconds.

Comment: @GEdgar Absolutely! Is this reasoning correct in general?

Comment: No, what If it was X squared instead of x?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig does this reasoning work when discussing the units of the derivative of *any* function at a point?

Comment: A derivative is an expression of rate of change at and instant.  There is no interval of $3$ seconds or $1$ second of $\frac 12$ a second or $7$ seconds.  In this case $1$ second is just a unit of time.  If you went to another planet where all their clocks measured time in a unit called the "three second" and it was three times as long $\frac 5{3}$ per second would equal $5$ per three second.  Likewise you could go to a strange country where they have something called "minutes" that are $20$ times slower than a "three-second" then it would be $100$ per minute.. .. wooo.....

Comment: @fleablood - thank you for your explanation. Just to be clear, when we compute the derivative in meters/second, we would say “five - thirds meters per second” since it’s at an instant?

Comment: note: if right this instant something is traveling at $\frac 53$ meters per second that does *NOT* mean it will travel $\frac 53$ meters *in* a second.  It could be speeding up  as we speak and travel more more in one second because in the second it speed increased to more tha $\frac 53$ per secon.  Or it could be slowing down and come to a stop in a second and travel less than that.  So $x$ meters per second only mean what the current velocity is at that *precise* moment.

Comment: " we would say “five - thirds meters per second” since it’s at an instant? "  mmmm..... no really.  we *always* say something is going $r$ rate and a rate is measure in $unit distance/unit time$ and that's how rates of speed are measured.  It's like you you get on a freeway an you spedometer says you are going $60$ miles an hour and you get off the freeway.  You were only on the freeway for thee seconds.  Does that me that in $1$ hour you would have gone $60$ miles? No, you were only on the freeway for three seconds.  If you maintained that speed for an hour than, yeah, but...

Comment: @fleablood - so if the derivative of a function at a point is $\frac{5}{3}$: how would we describe this in words then? Would we say “the rate of change at that point is $\frac{5}{3}$ meters per second”?

Comment: Yes, you would say exactly that.

Comment: ... assuming the function is one whose input are second units of time and whose output are meter units of measure.

Comment: @fleablood - gotcha! I’m assuming “five meters every three seconds” wouldn’t make much sense then?

Comment: ...since it’s the rate of change at a point.

Comment: But "five meters per 3 seconds" is okay (but weird) .  Also $\frac 53$ per second is okay, but $\frac 53$ *every* second is not correct.

Comment: @fleablood - quick follow up question: why is $\frac{5}{3}$ *every* second incorrect?

Comment: Because the guy isn't running at a constant speed for all eternity.  In one second he *won't* necessarily have gone $\frac 53$ meters further because maybe he slowed down and went less.  Maybe he sped up and went more. Maybe a sniper shot him and he dropped dead.

Comment: @fleablood - haha that’s a great explanation. Thank you for your patience and time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is saying “the rate of change is five-thirds meters per second” equivalent to saying “the rate of change is five meters every three seconds”?

Yes. To make things even simpler, the following two notions are equivalent:

- five-thirds meters per second
- five meters every three seconds

In general, if $p$ and $q$ are two positive integers,

- $p/q$ meters per second
- $p$ meters every $q$ seconds

are equivalent. Essentailly, you are looking at the function $y=\frac{p}{q}x$ in two different way by using two different "time unit":

- $\displaystyle y\ (\textrm{meters})=\frac{p}{q}\ (\textrm{meter}/\textrm{second})\cdot x(\textrm{seconds})$
- $\displaystyle y\ (\textrm{meters})=p\ 
  (\textrm{meter}/\color{red}{q\ \textrm{seconds}})\cdot x(\textrm{seconds})$

---

If you want to use the second interpretation, the "slope" needs to be rational. Imagine how you want to interpret $y=\pi x$.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Quick follow up: I’ve noticed with the derivative of a curve at a point we simply say “$m/n$ meters per second” rather than “$m$ meters every $n$ seconds”; why is that?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: I edited my answer. Saying (a) “/ meters per second” or (b)“ meters every  seconds” depends on what "time unit" one wishes to use: in (a) the time unit is "one second" while in (b) the time unit is "n seconds". In physics, they are simply two different ways to measure things while in mathematics, they are equivalent.

Comment: @TaylorRendon: for example, you can measure time by "every one second" or "every 60 seconds" (which is equivalent to "every one minute").

Comment: I see! So is there any particular reason why we use $(a)$ when measuring the derivative of a curve at a point? I haven’t heard $(b)$ used other than when measuring the slope of a line.

Comment: @TaylorRendon: well, they are equivalent as you observe. (b) works only when you have a rational number if you require the denominator to be an integer. (a) sticks to the original time unit, which is more desirable I suppose, since everybody can agree on *one* uniformly used. This is particularly useful when one *adds* two velocities.

Comment: @TaylorRendon: for example, one can add $\frac13(m/s)+\frac14(m/s)$ because both have the same time unit, but cannot (at least not directly) add $1(m/3s)+1(m/4s)$ since the time units are not the same.

Comment: Gotcha. I see that however in the comments above, JimJim, says my reasoning is not correct in general - why is that?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: JimJim was probably talking about $y=\frac{5}{3}x^2$. But your function is linear.

Comment: Gotcha, last question: so if the function is not linear one should use $(a)$ to avoid confusion as $(b)$ may not be true?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: in the nonlinear case, you are then talking about "*instant* rate change" and the slope of the tangent line. The two are still equivalent.

Comment: Another advantage is that you can immediately compare two velocities. It's immediately obvious that 8m/s is twice as fast as 4m/s, but not as easy to compare 260m/536s and 13m/67s.

Comment: Also, it allows us to write velocities as numbers that aren't formatted like ratios. A velocity of $0.3$m/s is understood to mean $0.3$ meters per$ 1 $second. This is simpatico with the property that any number $a$ is equal to $\frac{a}{1}$, i.e. every number already has "/1" built into it.  You can read velocity of $a$ m/s as $\frac{a}{1}$m/s. Velocity in m/s is just an example. Other physical measurements use similar conventions.

Comment: Working with scientific units, you will learn, is analogous to working with fractions, where students learn that before adding two fractions together, they need to make sure the denominators are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two statements are equivalent. Since you can think of the unit for rate of change in this case as fraction with meters divided by seconds. So the measurement  $\frac{5}{3}$ mps is the same as $\frac{5 \text{meters}}{3 \text{seconds}}$, or 5 meters per 3 seconds as you said.